# .ShowAllData on remaining sheet after all others deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete any sheet with a title that is not "PR11_P3".

In the remaining sheet there is a table "PR11_P3_Tabell" which is by now always filtered or rather sorted somehow and this is what I'm trying to restore with `.ShowAllData`.

```vb
Sub DeleteSheetRestoreSort()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "PR11_P3" Then
            ws.Delete
        Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        End If
    Next ws
   
End Sub
```

Comment: You may wish to edit this post as the code is doing the opposite of what you are saying.  Your post is saying that you delete every sheet with the name PR11_3P but what the code is doing is deleting every sheet except the one sheet that has the name PR11_P3.

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see that. I'll edit so grammatically its lees of a mess, English not my native tongue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `ActiveSheet` is the sheet you want to clear. Use `ws` instead.

```
Sub DeleteSheetRestoreSort()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "PR11_P3" Then
            ws.Delete
        Else
            If ws.filtermode then
                ws.ShowAllData
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Dose this do the same thing? Sub DeleteSheet()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "PR11_P3" Then
        ws.Delete
        'Else
        '    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData (wb)
    End If
    Next ws
    
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    
End Sub

Comment: If `ws` is PR11_P3 it clears the filter, otherwise it deletes the sheet, should be what you were trying to achieve. I fixed your `Else` also.

Comment: I got my wires crossed in my deleted comment, `ShowAllData` is definitely a method of worksheets, you were correct there originally. The issue is that `ActiveSheet` shouldn't really be relied upon, especially when you have an explicit worksheet ready to go.

Comment: Oh well no not really, delete all other sheets has to happen each time the macro is running, if there is no sheets to delete then it should do nothing (this is the dream scenario) and then regardless of what just happened in the code, the main sheet "PR11_P3" and its table "PR11_P3_Tabell" needs to get rid of sort value. To bullet proof this, if all data is showed then do nothing else, restore sort to show all data. I'm trying to make sure nothing in this code will break and the user of the file has to figure out what the hell am I supposed to do with a dialog box and the error.

Comment: Added in a line to get around the error if the sheet is not filtered. All other sheets are deleted each time it is run.

Comment: I agree.  I was checking before posting my comment but somehow it got entered before I could cancel the comment. Apologies to all